# C++ While loop check latest input int

Tags: c++

I need a program, that checks input number with latest input, and if it's true - show how many numbers were inputed (with latest 2 same);
Example:

Input: 3 5 24 4 3 5 3 5 3 5 5

Output: 11

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nr, am, last;
    cin >> nr;
    last = nr;
    am = 1;
    while (nr != last){
        cin >> nr;
        last = nr;
        am = am + 1;
    }
    cout << am;
    return 0;
}
```

I will rewrite code later to work with files, I just need to make it work first. Also, I don't want to get finished code, I want to know my misstakes, and or I'm going on right way. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the while guard last != nr is never true, because you read from cin first and then update last. This two statements should  be switched, also initialize last with (for example) -1, so the while loop is entered the first time.

initialize last:

```
last = -1;
```

in your while:

```
last = nr;
cin >> nr;
```

Comment: If first number inputed will be the number that was initialized for last (for ex. -1) it will stop and show that only 1 number was inputted.

Comment: That is right. To prevent that you should check the while condition at the end. So use a `do { .... } while (nr != last);` loop instead. In that case it does not matter how you initialized last.

Answer (score 1):

You never enter your while loop, because you're assigning `nr` to `last` just before your test:

```
last = nr;
// ...
while (nr != last){
 // ...
}
```

`while` condition is evaluated **before** entering the loop.